# Problems with subquery results and how to filtering it by IN

Tags: sql-server

My problem is about filtering rows with a subquery in sql server 2008.

Example,

```
create table A (article varchar(200),
                colour  varchar(200),
                size    varchar(200),
                prize   money)

create table B (article varchar(200),
                colour  varchar(200),
                size    varchar(200),
                prize   money)

content A

 - 00100221 BLANCO  39  30,00 
   00100221 BLANCO  40  30,00
   00100221 BLANCO  41  30,00 
   00100221 BLANCO  42  30,00
   00100221 BLANCO  43  30,00 
   00100221 BLANCO  44  30,00
   00100221 BLANCO  45  30,00 
   00100221 BLANCO  46  30,00
   00100221 GRIS    42  30,00 
   00100221 GRIS    43  30,00

content B

 - 00100221 BLANCO  39  3,00 
   00100221 BLANCO  40  30,00
   00100221 BLANCO  41  30,00 
   00100221 BLANCO  42  30,00
   00100221 BLANCO  43  30,00 
   00100221 BLANCO  44  30,00
   00100221 BLANCO  45  30,00 
   00100221 BLANCO  46  30,00
   00100221 GRIS    42  30,00 
   00100221 GRIS    43  30,00

select  A.* 
  from A  

 where A.article in 
                     ( 
                       select Article 
                         from B 
                        where B.Article = A.Article
                          and B.Colour = A.Colour
                          and B.size = A.size
                          and B.prize <> A.prize   
                     )
```

The result of this query is:

00100221    BLANCO  39  30,00

but I expect all the rows.

The result of the subquery is an article. But The main query show me only where match all the conditions in the subquery.

Comment: Can you show some sample data from both tables and your desired results?

Comment: My desired values is all the rows from A. All the rows that match the condition in the subquery.

Comment: You are only getting 1 row because of this in the subquery `and B.prize <> A.prize`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JOIN` instead:

```
select  v.* 
  from vu_oc_u_web_can v 
  join oc_u_web u ON u.Articulo = v.Articulo 
                      and u.Color = v.colorpro 
                      and u.Talla = v.talla
WHERE u.PVPRebaja <> v.preciorebtar
```

Comment: with the join is the same. Thanks,  Test with the new example. Its more simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the same shoe (?) data in table B with a different price, and that's only the first one! Maybe you are looking for something like that:

```
select A.*,
       case
        when B.Price <> A.Price then 'X'
        else ''
       end as HasDifferentPriceInTableB
  from A  
  join B on B.Article = A.Article and
            B.Colour  = A.Colour  and
            B.Size    = A.Size
```

Comment: your solution returns the same    00100221 BLANCO 39 30,00

Comment: I ask the shoes with all colours and sizes from the table A whose article have a different prize in the table B.

Comment: Right - and only the first one has a different price (3 instead of 30) in table B! All the other shoes have the same price in table A and B so they don't get returned.

Comment: I ask for All the rows from A whose article has a different prize in the table B. But i get only one, i think they should me return all the rows that match the principal condition. A.ARTICLE IN (SUBQUERY). My problem is that the subquery is filtering my result. In interbase this not happen

Comment: No! You ask for all rows in A with different price in B. Try my query, maybe that's kind of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Of what I read you want all rows of table A, even if the records in table b doesn't match the condition `A.prize <> B.prize` like this:

```
select  A.*, B.prize from A  
left outer join B on
B.article = A.article and
B.prize <> A.prize
```

This is what I understand of what you want with the query.

Comment: No, i think this is not the solution where there is a lot of articles, colours and sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
    select  A.* 
  from A  

 where A.article in 
                     ( 
                       select Article 
                         from B 
                         left join A X
                           on B.Article = X.Article
                          and B.Colour = X.Colour
                          and B.size = X.size
                          and B.prize <> X.prize   
                     )
```